# DFS Namespace is inaccessible when DC4 is up and running

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, dfs, dns-zone, namespaces

DC1, DC2 and DC3 are at site A. DC4 and DFS server (2008 R2) are at Site B. 
DC4 is Server 2003 and not a Global Catalog. DC1, DC2 and DC3 all are Server 2003, FSMO role holders and a Global Catalog. DC1 is Master DNS (SOA) for the Domain, All DC's are also DNS enabled.

Everything was working fine but suddenly after the monthly patch release the issue started. when we bring the DC4 up the DFS namespace is inaccessible. For workaround I have to keep the DC4 down. Please let me know any suggestions to look at this issue?

Comment: `1.` DC4 should be a Global Catalog server. `2.` You seem to be implying that DC1, 2 and 3 are all FSMO role holders. Do you mean that each of them holds on or more FSMO roles that are split between the three, because it isn't possible for them all to hold the same FSMO roles. `3.` When you say that DC1 is the Master DNS server are you implying that your AD DNS zones **are not** AD integrated? If your AD DNS zones **are** AD integrated then there's no real `master` server, each DC is the `master` (or authoritative) server for it's copy of your DNS zones.

Comment: The namespace is inaccessible from both sites or just Site B? Do you have any AD replication issues?

Comment: Yes, we do have AD replication issues between both the sites,FSMO roles are distributed between the three servers at Site A. All DC's are DNS zone integrated but I mean to say that DC1 is Start of Authority aka DNS Master  Server which transfers the zone with external/secondary DNS servers. Site B only needs to access the DFS namespace. when I run repadmin /replsummary from DC4 I get replication database error 8541 for DC1 and accessing the hard disk, a disk operation failed error 1127 for DC2 and DC3. Could be database and zone replication the root cause?